# result.wait() does nothing but hang and doesn't give 8 for result=add.delay(4,4)

Tags: celery-task

add is the task from celery doc.  I'm just so confused why it does'nt yield 8 as it should, but instead does nothing but hang.

Comment: even result.get() just hangs.  Why?

Comment: I'm thinking that I didn't set this up correctly:  CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = "sqlite:///mydatabase.db" since I don't have a mydatabase.db file.  And if I created one, I don't know where to put it.

Comment: BTW, I'm using AMQP and have rabbitmq installed and running.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try setting result back-end, this fixed problem in my [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111040/celery-result-get-times-out/7153634#7153634)

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
```

Comment: It's not BROKER_RESULT_BACKEND like I just wasted hours on. What was very strange in my case was that from the interpreter result.get() hung but a python script of the exact same code worked just fine.