# Celery result.get times out

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I have two different django projects say `projA` and `projB`, each have its own celery daemon running on separate queues but same vhost, projA have a task `taskA` and projB have a task `taskB`, I try to run `taskB` from inside `taskA` e.g.

```
@task(routing_key='taskA')
def taskA(event_id):
    # do some work , then call taskB and wait for result
    result = send_task('taskB',routing_key='taskB')
    res = result.get(timeout=20)
```

I can see in logs of projB that taskB finished within a second, but taskA keeps on waiting for result and times out after 20 seconds

For backend I have rabbitmq.

Comment: This warns against launching subtasks, but if taskB is completing may not be the cause of your problem:
http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/tasks.html#task-synchronous-subtasks

Comment: yes it is warning for possible deadlocks, but I have 7 concurrent process for each queue, and only 1 task so it should not happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the result back-end fixed the problem

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
CELERY_AMQP_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 1000
```

IMO if result back-end is not set result.get should throw error or at-least log a warning

Though celery 2.3 does throw error as described here https://github.com/ask/django-celery/issues/66